# How to configure a remember me aware listener in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

I have implemented a [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) successfully, but now I also need to add 'remember me' functionality, and I couldn't find docs on how to do that.

I tried adding this:

```
remember_me:
    key: "%secret%"
    lifetime: 31536000 # 1 year
    always_remember_me: true
```

But it says this:

`You must configure at least one remember-me aware listener (such as form-login) for each firewall that has remember-me enabled.`

I found this but I'm not sure how to use it: `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\RememberMeAuthenticationProvider`

So where is the `RememberMeAwareInterface`? (I guess there is one? Like ContainerAware) And what should I do with it?

I don't think I need to write my own implementation, the default one should work fine with my custom auth provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue with a custom Facebook authentication provider I wrote. The solution ended up being pretty simple:

I'll assume you implemented a custom authentication provider with a custom `SecurityFactoryInterface` implementation that extends from `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\AbstractFactory`. If you did this, the rest is a matter of configuration:

1. In your security configuration, configure the `remember_me` functionality for your firewall. Assuming you're configuring that into the `public` firewall, the added config params might look something like this:

   ```
   firewalls:
       public:
           remember_me:
               key:      "%secret%"
               lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
               path:     /
               domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
   ```
2. In the same configuration, enable the remember_me functionality for your authentication provider. Assuming you're configuring that into the `public` firewall and your `SecurityFactoryInterface` implementation's `getKey()` method returns `yourAuthProviderKey`, the added config params might look something like this:

   ```
   firewalls:
       public:
           yourAuthProviderKey:
               remember_me:        true
   ```
3. Finally, when your Authentication Provider handles logins, make sure you request the remember me feature by having an http GET or POST parameter named `_remember_me` with value `1` in the http request. (Note though: this parameter might need a different name if you changed its default value in your security config.) For example, in my case, I had to tell Facebook to redirect to the following URL after it handled the authentication: `http://www.mydomain.com/auth-callback/?_remember_me=1`. (Note the part after the `?`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: For anyone else coming from Google: things like Remember Me and Referer will only work if your getPosition() in the class extending from AbstractFactory returns a position that is late enough in the pipeline. I couldn't find exact descriptions of the various strings accepted, but, e.g. 'pre_auth' is too early for remember me and referer to work automatically, but 'form' works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add this to your `form_login` section?

```
form_login:
    remember_me: true
```

Comment: No, I don't have one. I'm using my own auth provider `NoPasswordProvider`, users log in via a one-time link that is sent to their email address. So in my firewall, instead of form_login, I have `nopassword: true`

Answer (score 1):

From Symfony 2.8, the "key" is replaced by "secret". So you will have:

```
remember_me:
   secret: %secret%
   lifetime: 31536000
```

If you run across this error, that is the fix

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
firewalls:                   
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /the-cao
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened when i create a Factory class implementing SecurityFactoryInterface (as it was described in example "How to Create a custom Authentication Provider"). Later i found that another way to create this Factory is extending from AbstractFactory which contains neccessary readme stuff (you can find it create() method). So there are two solutions: 1) extend AbstractFactory instead of implementing SecurityFactoryInterface 2) implement SecurityFactoryInterface and copypaste readme related code. In symfony 3.1:

```
       // add remember-me aware tag if requested
    if ($this->isRememberMeAware($config)) {
        $container
            ->getDefinition($listenerId)
            ->addTag('security.remember_me_aware', array('id' => $id, 'provider' => $userProviderId))
        ;
    }
```