# Implement remember_me option with http_basic auth in SF2 SecurityBundle

Tags: php, security, symfony, remember-me, basic-authentication

I think that I already know the answer (*as I really cannot see where to put the checkbox*) so forgive this question that might be stupid but **is there anyway to implement the `remember_me` option with an `http_basic` authentication in a Symfony2 project?**

I'm talking of such a `security.yml` configuration

```
firewalls:
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        http_basic: ~
        stateless:  true
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, parameter: _want_to_be_this_user }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe this answer will help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14304346/2160958

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look deeper into this way.

Comment: @Vardius Unfortunately, this answer provides a way to do so with a `custom` authentication. I'm using `http_basic`. Still in the blur then.